# Is there a library for HUGE integers

Tags: java, biginteger, polynomial-math, integer-overflow

I am looking for a Java library that can handle truly huge numbers or suggestions as to how to implement this myself. We are talking way beyond `BigInteger`. How about **2^39614081257132168796771974655+1** for example.

Clearly I could, theoretically, make use of a `TreeSet<BigInteger>`, one entry per bit and do all the math old-school but I am looking for something that can actually do some real maths with these numbers using built-in math hardware. I don't expect anything truly fast but I would very much like to get close.

It is likely that the number of set bits may be  quite small - I am representing G2 polynomials.

Does anyone know of anything out there?

I suspect a feature of the package must be a `setBit(BigInteger i)`.

**Added**

Thanks for the suggestion of [Apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/). Sadly the following is not possible. It complains that the second parameter must be a `long`.

```
    Apint two = new Apint(2);
    Apint big = new Apint("39614081257132168796771974655");
    ApintMath.pow(two, big);
```

Please note that I am also open to suggestions as to how to do this myself.

**Added** - to attempt a reopen.

Please see [user2246674's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17158954/823393) reminding us how staggeringly enormous these numbers are - I can assure you we are not talking about some ordinary math library here, we are talking some serious `Math.pow(age-of-the-universe,atoms-in_the_galaxy)` kind of numbers - we are **certainly** not looking for mere *opinionated answers*.

Comment: This is a "shopping list" question, which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. (Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

Comment: Added *or suggestions as to how to implement this myself*.

Comment: I added "in notation" to the title and emphasis on HUGE - clearly integers of this size *cannot* be feasibly represented in standard integer encodings. So, while it may be a "shopping question", it is also asking for a *very focused library or approach*.

Comment: @user2246674 - Not sure if you have the English right - could you revisit please?

Comment: @user2246674 - drastically simplified - good?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Consider searching for math libraries that can "solve algebraic equations" (i.e. like matlab); there might be some relevant results.

Comment: A `TreeSet<BigInteger>` sounds good to me, quite honestly.

Comment: Which is why apfloat is what is needed in OP's case

Comment: @LouisWasserman - It does indeed work but it is hideously slow for almost any real application.

Comment: Interesting question. Are you still using Apint? ...Writing a library for bit-wise sparse big number would be a nice project!

Comment: @mike - I experimented with Apint, it didn't help. I have started to tinker with a sparse huge number library but it won't be ready soon - this is a home project for me.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't an answer; it is here because I think it's important to realize *how insanely big* such a number is and why a standard arbitrary precision math library will not work - ever.

The library *must* have support to directly deal with higher-order equations (such as that which powers [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)). I believe this is a good question to have on SO specifically because numbers of this magnitude *must* be treated special.

---

A standard bit encoding *won't* work here - if this were possible then BigInteger would also likely suffice (as would Apfloat which was mentioned). The fundamental problem is that 2^39614081257132168796771974655 is *huge*. Like, *really, really big*. It only makes sense to deal with numbers of this size using equations!

Let's reason how much a standard one's or two's complement encoding takes by looking at the storage required for several common maximum integer values:

- 2^8 takes 8 bits; or 1 byte (8/8)
- 2^32 takes 32 bits; or 4 bytes (32/8)
- 2^64 takes 64 bits; or 8 bytes (64/8)

Thus, 2^39614081257132168796771974655 requires 39614081257132168796771974655/8 (or ~5x10^27) bytes of memory if using a similar encoding.

A terabyte of memory is only 1x10^12 bytes: **it requires more than a QUADRILLION TERABYTES to use a standard encoding on a number of this magnitude**.

Comment: Good narrative - the ironic part of it all is that 2^39614081257132168796771974655 has just **one** bit set in it. Every single other bit of your quadrillion terabytes is actually zero!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do math on this, but only symbolic based calculation, i.e. you cannot reduce this to a real number, you can only process this an expression.

Can you give some example of the operations you want to perform?

Comment: I want to test [primitivity](http://www.theory.cs.uvic.ca/~cos/inf/neck/PolyInfo.html) of a 96bit G(2) polynomial.

Comment: For that you need an algaberic library so you don't need to evaluate the value and you will need some smart mathematics to avoid a brute force search e.g. you need something like `(a^n + b^n)` where n is odd = `(a + b)*sumOf(i from 0 to n, - * -1 ^ i * a^i * b^(n-1-i))` which means since your power is odd, you can apply this and it can be factorised.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The nice thing about working in G(2) is that most of the standard math functions have binary equivalents. E.G add/sub are actually **both** xor if you hold the poly as bits.

Comment: Excellent intro [here](http://www.ee.unb.ca/tervo/ee4253/poly.shtml).